# ASP.NET MVC + jQuery - How can I preserve .NET line-endings when I $.post a form via jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, serialization, asp.net-mvc-3

Here is what my jQuery code is doing:

```
 $('.newCommentBox form').live('submit', function () {

    //Submit the form post
    $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function (data) { showNewComment(data) });

    return false;
});
```

Whenever a form is submitted, I take the results, serialize them, and send them to the specific action via a POST. When we get a response back from the server, I invoke the showNewComment function to display the comment being added in real-time.

Here is my issue: I need to be able to preserve the whitespace people leave in their comments so they can control the readability of longer comments. I use a .NET Html helper method to convert CRLF linebreaks into `<br/>` tags when the comments get rendered, but all of those line-endings are not preserved when the form is submitted via jQuery and serialized via JSON, whereas when I did this without AJAX it worked just fine.

How can I preserve these line endings, or what did jQuery replace the CRLF line-endings with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ajax, I've seen line breaks being posted as \r\n and \n depending on browser and environment, but in general, I found that checking for \n and replace it with `<br />` is the safest bet.

For example in C#:

```
"Hello\nWorld".Replace("\n", "<br />");
or
"Hello\r\nWorld".Replace("\n", "<br />");
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use the CSS white-space property to style your output.

```
<div style="white-space: pre;">
    Hello
World
</div>
```

should be rendered as

```
    Hello
World
```

with tabs and linespacing preserved

See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#white-space-prop for more info